# How to get http request object in displaytag decorator?

Tags: displaytag

I using display tag for my application. to render the table in some format i am using decorator. But in decorator method i need Http request object. How do i get it?

Comment: What kind of decorator?  Column or table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this.getpageContext() method we can get the request object. this.getpageContext() method is available in the super class.